# main div won't scale to content in combination with sticky footer

Tags: css, overflow, footer, scaling, sticky

Can somebody help me out here? [view page here](http://www.pencilpoint.nl/_klanten/bollandhuis/buitenland.htm)

I'm having problems with my #mainvervolg div, which is not scaling to content. It has a min-height and an overflow: auto; because of the sticky footer i use. I have no clue as to how I can fix the non-scaling.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you must move the div #contentCONTAINER out of div #slidercontainer and into #mainvervolg, and move the #footerwrap div inside the #mainvervolg. This will allow the document to flow correctly. Then change the css to match below:

```
#mainvervolg {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
#slidercontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 275px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#contentCONTAINER {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    top: -50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The notable changes are removing width, position, min-height and padding-bottom off the main canvas. Change the top to -50px on the contentCONTAINER.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm gonna try it asap.

Comment: Uhm.. so here's why that's not working for me. The footer then becomes fixed at the bottom, with the content scrolling underneath it. I don't want that. I don't want the footer visible when the content is long enough. It should react to the divs before it and just close the page. I only want the footer visible at first when the content is smaller than the browser window, so the footer will fill up the bottom of the browser nicely. Example is visible at the index: [link](http://www.pencilpoint.nl/_klanten/bollandhuis)

Comment: Updating the answer to achieve this, hope thats what you were after

Answer (score 0):

Okay in this case, i think i got it: the only thing i changed now is removing the 'overflow:auto' from the contentCONTAINER and it seems to work now. Correct me if i'm wrong.